# mongodb import .... taking very long time

Tags: mongodb

I have json file of 432.6 MB, which i am uploading to mongodb database, I have mongodb setup on my OS X 10.9.4

```
mongoimport -d fastqdb -c seqcol --file /Users/loginname/FASTQ.json --jsonArray
connected to: 127.0.0.1
2014-07-29T18:06:54.311+0200        Progress: 31598/432568845   0%
2014-07-29T18:06:54.311+0200            200 66/second
2014-07-29T18:06:58.207+0200        Progress: 78998/432568845   0%
2014-07-29T18:06:58.208+0200            500 71/second
...........................
...............................
2014-07-30T13:42:32.027+0200        Progress: 138486966/432568845   32%
2014-07-30T13:42:32.027+0200            860200  12/second
2014-07-30T13:42:36.004+0200        Progress: 138534798/432568845   32%
2014-07-30T13:42:36.004+0200            860500  12/second
```

one can check the time, it is almost a day and still it is running
details of my PC
Memory  4 GB 1067 MHz DDR3
Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo
Processor Speed:    2.66 GHz

I like to mention, I am very new to mongodb and nosql, actually this is my first interaction. I am not sure. what need to be changed. Actually this is my test run, I have to work with 5TB of data, so wanted to check, is it possible to store such large data with  mongodb. I will be using 10-12 nodes cluster.

After I finished

```
2014-07-30T16:52:07.143+0200 imported 1407471 objects 
> use fastqdb
switched to db fastqdb
> show collections
seqcol
system.indexes
> db.seqcol.count()
1407471
> db.seqcol.find()
> 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a2563ff562b85ce94b") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce94c") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce94d") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce94e") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce94f") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce950") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce951") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce952") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce953") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d7c4a4563ff562b85ce954") }
```

only id's are created , there are no data, and my data consist of

```
[
    {
        "POS": "*",
        "MAPQ": "0",
        "`SEQ": "CTGGTGGGATACAGAACAGTACAATTCTGATGGTAATCAGTTAACAAATTAAACATATTTATTTTATAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACC"
    },

    {
        "POS": "*",
        "MAPQ": "0",
        "`SEQ": "AGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGCTAGGGTTAGGGTAAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTATGGTTAGGGTTAGTGGTAGGGTTAGGTTTAGGGG"
    },

    {
        "POS": "*",
        "MAPQ": "0",
        "`SEQ": "CTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTCTAACCCTAACCCTA"
    },
```

Ok I found out my solution with GridFS. 
file1.py

```
import pymongo
import gridfs

db = pymongo.connection.Connection().<databasename>

grid = gridfs.GridFS(db)
x = open("/Users/<name>/"filename")
grid.put(x,filename = "filename")
```

file2.py .....retrieving data

```
import pymongo,gridfs

db = pymongo.connection.Connection('localhost',27017).<databasename>
grid = gridfs.GridFS(db)
fp = grid.get_last_version(filename='filename')

with grid.get(fp._id) as fp_read:
    print fp_read.read()
```

it took me 44 sec. check out [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhWySVTNOA0][1]

I am not sure if this is correct way, one has to read about mongoDB GridFS

Comment: Removing indexes and re-indexing after the import can speed things up.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638845/fastest-way-to-import-millions-of-json-documents-to-mongodb

Comment: With 5TB is better to shard since you have 12 nodes availiable

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? I just attempted this with 2.4.10 and it inserted the documents as expected - I can't reproduce the _id only result you are seeing

Comment: Also the backtick at the start of the SEQ fieldname is a bit odd but it works in my testing - I'm wondering if the version you are using is not so forgiving.